# Create a multiple object with dynamic names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a function which allows to return an object whose name change to each loop.

I done this function like this :

```
function createObjPack(index){
    var currentPack = packVehicule[key].libelle;

    return [eval(currentPack + ' = {}' ), calcul(currentPack, key)];
};
```

The variable `curentPack` contains the name of the current object.
The return must generate a object which name match the value of `currentPack`

I thought read the `currentPack` directly into an `eval()` function for change dynamicly  the name but, it doesn't work.

Someone can help me ?

Comment: I think the parameter index should be named key shouldn't it?

Comment: Dnamic variable names seems like the wrong thing. Use an object whose keys are the dynamic names. And you don't need to use `eval` to create dynamic variable names, just assign `window[currentPack]`, since all global variables are properties of `window`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use dynamic variable names, use an object.

```
var packs = {}

function createObjPack(index) {
    var currentPack = packvehicule[index].libelle;
    var newPack = {};
    packs[currentPack] = newPack;
    return [newPack, calcul(currentPack, index)];
}
```